# Xsd with Enumeration - Getting error while puting enumeration type

Tags: enums, xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation

I am tryin to add Enumeration type as you can see below. it adds string type but i need enum Values when jaxb converts xsd to java class. I used simpletype which converts it into string but not sure how to change it inside element as if I try to change it it gives me error.

```
<xs:element name="DeletionReq">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:long"/>
                <xs:element name="isNewProcess" type="xs:boolean" default="false"/>
                <xs:element name="data" type="tns:data" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="data">
    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="dataColumnName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="dataOldValue"   type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="dataNewValue"   type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="testRecord"   type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="projId"   type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="allowedApplDataColumnNames">
                          <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                              <xs:enumeration value="code1" />
                              <xs:enumeration value="code2" />
                              <xs:enumeration value="code3" />
                              <xs:enumeration value="code4" />
                              <xs:enumeration value="code5" />
                            </xs:restriction>
                          </xs:simpleType>
                       </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an explicit type from your enum:

```
    <xs:simpleType name="myEnum">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="code1" />
            <xs:enumeration value="code2" />
            <xs:enumeration value="code3" />
            <xs:enumeration value="code4" />
            <xs:enumeration value="code5" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="data">
        <xs:sequence>
            ...
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="allowedApplDataColumnNames" type="tns:myEnum"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: allowedApplDataColumnNames comes as Object i need to generated Java class as Enum with restrictive values. we have simpletype i guess it dont allow it to convert to enum..    https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/02/jaxb-nuance-string-versus-enum-enumerated-restricted-xsd-string.html

Comment: it worked when i put simple type myenum on top and generated class. thank you

Comment: Strange. I never discovered that the element/type order within Schema was important. I use org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:3.1.0 for Schema to Java translation.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the type outside of the complexType `data` like the following :

```xml
<xs:simpleType name="allowedApplDataColumnNamesType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="code1" />
        <xs:enumeration value="code2" />
        <xs:enumeration value="code3" />
        <xs:enumeration value="code4" />
        <xs:enumeration value="code5" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="data">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="dataColumnName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="dataOldValue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="dataNewValue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="testRecord" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="projId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="allowedApplDataColumnNames" type="tns:allowedApplDataColumnNamesType" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: it doenst work as it complains . i used type="tns:allowedApplDataColumnNamesType" it worked. above give me exception type not found in generated java class

Comment: I've added the `tns` prefix to my answer ;)

Comment: I haven't added the tns in the first place since it depends from your header definition. If you define for example : `<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:myns="http://example.com" targetNamespace="http://example.com" version="1.0">`, the good prefix would be `myns:` and not `tns:`